# Why should I convert all strings to constants in Python?

Tags: python, constants

I don't know if this will be useful to the community or not, as it might be unique to my situation. I'm working with a senior programmer who, in his code, has this peculiar habit of turning all strings into constants before using them. And I just don't get why. It doesn't make any sense to me. 99% of the time, we are gaining no abstraction or expressive power from the conversion, as it's done like this:

```
URL_CONVERTER = "url_converter"
URL_TYPE_LONG = "url_type_long"
URL_TYPE_SHORT = "url_type_short"
URL_TYPE_ARRAY = [URL_TYPE_LONG, URL_TYPE_SHORT]
for urltype in URL_TYPE_ARRAY:
    outside_class.validate(urltype)
```

Just like that. As a rule, the constant name is almost always simply the string's content, capitalized, and these constants are seldom referenced more than once anyway. Perhaps less than 5% of the constants thus created are referenced twice or more during runtime.

Is this some programming technique that I just don't understand? Or is it just a bad habit? The other programmers are beginning to mimic this (possibly bad) form, and I want to know if there is a reason for me to as well before blindly following.

Thanks!

Edit: Updated the example. In addition, I understand everyone's points, and would add that this is a fairly small shop, at most two other people will ever see anyone's code, never mind work on it, and these are pretty simple one-offs we're building, not complicated workers or anything. I understand why this would be good practice in a large project, but in the context of our work, it comes across as too much overhead for a very simple task.

Comment: Provide an example in context.  In other words, show us one of the strings, and show us it being used in a piece of code.

Comment: Would love to, but can't share our code. I'll update the example with a reasonable facsimile.

Comment: @StormShadow - I think my answer still applies to your updated question.  In the sample code you gave, you are not in any of the four scenarios I listed (or any other like them).  Hence, it is not a smart use of the code.  So, with this specific example, I'd say no, you shouldn't do that.  Those lines/variables are unnecessary here.  Once again though, you need to be smart about it.  Do what works best/has the most advantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are a few scenarios where this would be a good practice:

1. You have a long string that will be used in a lot of places.  Thus, you put it in a (presumably shorter) variable name so that you can use it easily.  This keeps the lines of your code from becoming overly long/repetitive.
2. (somewhat similar to #1) You have a long sting that can't fit on a certain line without sending it way off the screen.  So, you put the string in a variable to keep the lines concise.
3. You want to save a string and alter (add/remove characters from) it latter on.  Only a variable will give you this functionality.
4. You want to have the ability to change multiple lines that use the same string by just altering one variable's value.  This is a lot easier than having to go through numerous lines looking for occurrences of the string.  It also keeps you from possibly missing some and thereby introducing bugs to your code.

Basically, the answer is to be smart about it.  Ask yourself: will making the string into a variable save typing?  Will it improve efficiency?  Will it make your code easier to work with and/or maintain?  If you answered "yes" to any of these, then you should do it.

Answer (score 6):

It helps to keep your code congruent. E.g. if you use URL_TYPE_LONG in both your client and your server and for some reason you need to change its string value, you just change one line. And you don't run the risk of forgetting to change one instance in the code, or to change one string in your code which just hazardly has the same value.

Even if those constants are only referenced once now, who are we to foresee the future...

I think this also arises from a time (when dinosaurs roamed the earth) when you tried to (A) keep data and code seperated and (B) you were concerned about how many strings you had allocated.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this is a really good idea.. I work on a fairly large python codebase with 100+ other engineers, and vouch for the fact that this makes collaboration much easier.

If you directly used the underlying strings everywhere, it would make it easier for you to make a typo when referencing it in one particular module and could lead to hard-to-catch bugs.

Its easier for modern IDE's to provide autocomplete and refactoring support when you are using a variable like this. You can easily change the underlying identifier to a different string or even a number later; This makes it easier for you to track down all modules referencing a particular identifier.